# Not able to resize, shrink partition as I installed Ubuntu on my entire hdd

Tags: partitioning, resize

I am completely new to Ubuntu. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on my HP pavilion dm4 2165dx. I was previously running windows 8 on my laptop. I did a complete format and installed Ubuntu. But i installed it on my entire HDD and I was not able resize it using gpart also...

Here is the image of my hdd in gparted,

[image: Gparted with current hdd paritioning]

Comment: Try booting from a live cd/usb and then run GPardEd to alter your partitions.

Answer (score 2):

You can resize a mounted partition. Run [`gparted live disk`](http://gparted.org/download.php) to resize your HDD partition.

OR

Boot your `Ubuntu installation disk`. Click on `Try Ubuntu`. After that, open the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> and run the below commands to install gparted.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

Comment: You can also run gparted from ubuntu live iso.

Comment: @avinash-raj gparted will already be installed in the *buntu install medium

Answer (score -1):

You should try again with the live CD and redo your partitions something like this :

/ 20gb

/home 570gb

swap 10gb

You can do that by choosing 'something else' when the install disk gets to how you want to install Ubuntu.

If you've got any data you don't want to lose back it up first